How can I correctly mirror an animation so I can retarget it to a left handed character
I have a rig with an animation that I want to flip and then retarget with Rokoko to a different rig of a left handed character. I tried the negative scale trick from this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKGWD65wqxo) and things seemed fine on the main rig. But when I applied the retarget (also changing L->R and R->L in the bone list), the rotations of the second rig were all messed up. Mirroring the animation with Ctrl->M,X gave the same result. Is there another method to mirror animations or am I doing something wrong?
